# Сравнение значаний с троке по условию со всеми значениями в этом столбце

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение

У меня есть DataFrame:

```
    Item      Year  Week   Qnty   Start_season 
 1  160947    2018   01     0          0
 2  160947    2018   08     0          0
 3  160947    2018   09     9          1
 4  160947    2018   10    12          1
 5  160947    2018   11    99          1
```

Где Item - товар, Year - год продаж, Week - неделя продаж, Qnty - сумма продаж за эту неделю, Start_season- период начала сезона

Мне нужно найти период окончания сезона и сделать отдельное поле в котором запишется флаг 1 - конец сезона в эту неделю был, 0 - конца сезона в эту неделю не было.
За окончание сезона принимается период, где значения Qnty (суммарные значение за неделю) отличаются от значений Qnty при Start_season = 1 (начало сезона) на +/- 10%.

Пробовала вот так:

```
df['Finish_season'] = np.where((df['Start_season'] == 1) & (ufloat((df['Qnty'].shift(-1) - df['Qnty'])/df['Qnty']*100 , 10)),1,0)
```

Но это не работает.

В качестве результата хотелось бы получить следующий DataFarme:

```
    Item      Year  Week   Qnty   Start_season  Finish_season
 1  160947    2018   01     0          0            0 
 2  160947    2018   08     0          0            0
 3  160947    2018   09     9          1            0
 4  160947    2018   10    12          1            1
 5  160947    2018   11    99          1            1
```

При получении столбца Finish_season мы сравниваем во сколько раз Qnty= 12 больше Qnty = 9 & Start_season=1, если значение в процентах +/- 10 выставляем Finish_season = 1.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе желаемый результат?

Comment: @MaxU поля Year, Week сортированы по возрастанию и сначала мы находим первое значение Qnty, где Start_season = 1, затем его сравниваем со значением Qnty в следующей строке. Если больше или меньше на 10 % то Finish_season=1, если разница больше диапазона 10% выставляем 0.

Comment: непонятно почему строка 4 не отмечена как `Finish_season` - 12/9 = 1.333, т.е. +33% ??

Comment: @MaxU да, простите, это я ошиблась. там должна быть 1

Comment: @MaxU подскажите, как зафиксировать число на которое мы делим?
В нашем случае - это 9. Мы всегда сравниваем с тем числом которое первый раз встретилось в поле Qnty при первой условии Start_season = 1. И сравнение последующее идет каждой строки в этим числом, уже не зависимо от условия Start_season = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mask = df.eval("Start_season == 1")

df["Finish_season"] = 0

df.loc[mask, "Finish_season"] = \
    np.where(np.abs(df.loc[mask].groupby("Item")["Qnty"].pct_change() - 1) > 0.1, 1, 0)
```

результат:

```
In [151]: df
Out[151]:
     Item  Year  Week  Qnty  Start_season  Finish_season
1  160947  2018     1     0             0              0
2  160947  2018     8     0             0              0
3  160947  2018     9     9             1              0
4  160947  2018    10    12             1              1
5  160947  2018    11    99             1              1
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> если значение, с которым сравниваем у нас постоянное? В нашем примере
>   мы каждое число в последующей строчке делим только на 9

```
tresh = 9
df.loc[mask, "Finish_season"] = \
    np.where(np.abs(df.loc[mask].groupby("Item")["Qnty"].apply(lambda x: x/tresh) - 1) > 0.1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: если значение, с которым сравниваем у нас постоянное? В нашем примере мы каждое число в последующей строчке делим только на 9.